# Form validation not working using onsubmit

Tags: javascript

My form validation used to work but now I cannot figure out what is wrong.
When entering an email or username you always get a pop-up with the error

> Username or Email is needed

Remove each check one by one and you get the next error message

```
    <form method='POST' name='signIn' onsubmit='return checkLoginForm(this);'>
        <input type='hidden' name='action' value='signIn'>
        <div class='enterInfo' align='left'>Username or Email 1:</div><input size='60' type='text' name='username' class='input' id='theFieldID'></div>
        <div class='enterInfo' align='left'>Password: <input id='username' size='60' type='password' name='pswd' class='input'></div>
        <div class='agreement' align='left'>&nbsp;</div>
        <input type='submit' value='Log In'>
    </form>
```

Here is the js

```
function checkLoginForm(form) {

if(form.username.value == "") {
    alert("Username or Email is needed");
    form.username.focus();
    return false;
}
if(form.username.value.length < 4) {
    alert("Username or Email is to short");
    form.username.focus();
    return false;
}
re = /^[-_a-zA-Z0-9.,@#!?]*$/;
if(!re.test(form.username.value)) {
    alert("Username or Email only contains letters, numbers and _-.,@#!?");
    form.username.focus();
    return false;
}


if(form.pswd.value == ""){
    alert("Password is needed");
    form.pwd1.focus();
    return false;
}   
return true;
```

}

Comment: You have two elements whose id/name is 'username', for a start. Ensure that each of your elements has a unique id. And your validation check for username or email being too short is only checking the username value. Ensure these are distinctly checked in your validation.

Comment: Thanks! That got changed and I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to access to this kind of elements is By Id. Also, for more optimization and comfortable, it's better to assign a variable to the element one time and use that variable for the next times:

```js
function checkLoginForm(form) {
usn = document.getElementById("theFieldID");
pwd = document.getElementById("password");
if(usn.value == "") {
    alert("Username or Email is needed");
    usn.focus();
    return false;
}
if(usn.value.length < 4) {
    alert("Username or Email is to short");
    usn.focus();
    return false;
}
re = /^[-_a-zA-Z0-9.,@#!?]*$/;
if(!re.test(usn.value)) {
    alert("Username or Email only contains letters, numbers and _-.,@#!?");
    usn.focus();
    return false;
}


if(pwd.value == ""){
    alert("Password is needed");
    pwd.focus();
    return false;
}   
return true;
}
```

```html
<form method='POST' name='signIn' onsubmit='return checkLoginForm(this);'>
   <input type='hidden' name='action' value='signIn'>
   <div class='enterInfo' align='left'>Username or Email 1:</div><div>
      <input size='60' type='text' name='username' class='input' id='theFieldID'></div>
   <div class='enterInfo' align='left'>Password: <input id='password' size='60' type='password' name='pswd' class='input'></div>
   <div class='agreement' align='left'>&nbsp;</div>
   <input type='submit' value='Log In'>
  </form>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, I will take this code and figure out what I did wrong

Comment: @harkly, I'm glad to hear that. The thing that was wrong with your code was the part you were trying to focus on an element. It couldn't access the element on your way. So, it couldn't parse the 'return false;'

Comment: @harkly, if you believe the answer works, please accept the answer. So, no more user would take time on this ticket.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to figure out how to do "close" it.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of thing:

```
if(form.username.value == "") {
    alert("Username or Email is needed");
    form.username.focus();
    return false;
}
```

You are better off directly accessing the object:

```
if(document.getElementById("theFieldID").value == "") {
    alert("Username or Email is needed");
    form.username.focus();
    return false;
}
```

In any case, you need to pay attention to what your names and IDs are on those elements.  For instance, you are passing in "form" as an argument, but with no name or ID specified, there is nothing to tell it *which* form you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

`input type ="submit"` will submit the form ,

You need to use `event.preventDefault` to prevent the default behavior and to perform validation

Also `form.username.focus()` & `form.username.focus();` will throw  `not a function` error

[image: **Error Snapshot**]

You need use `document.getElmentById(someElement').focus()`

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/j0q0gqca/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function checkLoginForm() {
                var eleuser = document.forms["signIn"]["username"];
                var elepass = document.forms["signIn"]["pswd"];
                 var username = eleuser.value;
                 var pass =  elepass.value;
                if(username == "") {
                    alert("Username or Email is needed");
                    eleuser.focus();
                    return false;
                }
            if(username.length < 4) {
                alert("Username or Email is to short");
                eleuser.focus();
                return false;
            }
            re = /^[-_a-zA-Z0-9.,@#!?]*$/;
            if(!re.test(username)) {
                alert("Username or Email only contains letters, numbers and _-.,@#!?");
                eleuser.focus();
                return false;
            }
            if(pass == ""){
                alert("Password is needed");
                elepass.focus();
                return false;
            }   
            return true;
                        }
        </script>
        
        <form method="post" name='signIn' onsubmit='return checkLoginForm();'>
        <div class='enterInfo' align='left'>Username or Email 1:</div>
            <input size='60' type='text' name='username' class='input' id='theFieldID'>
        <div class='enterInfo'> Password: </div>
            <input id='username1' size='60' type='password' name='pswd' class='input'>
            <br><br>
           <input type='submit' value='Log In'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```